# I arrive in Abu Dhabi at 1 am and have 9 hours layover, what is there to do at this time in the morning?

Tags: layovers, abu-dhabi

I will arrive at the airport around 1 am and I've got 9 hours to kill, or lets say 7 before I go back to the airport. What is there to do at this time in the morning?

Answer (score 1):

Restaurants and shops are all open 24x7 [according to their web site](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/).